# vector arrow with superscript

Tags: superscripts, vector

I want to have a vector with a superscript:

```
\vec{o}^t
```

But this gives very bad results: the t is overlapping with the vector arrow. How do I fix this (and why does this give bad results in the first place) ?

Comment: I like it quick \vec o to show a vector on top of o in Latex. This just works with single letter.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I don't really know why the result is bad; I suspect it has to do with the width of the letter. I wouldn't use such a notation, but that's a personal opinion.

With

```
\vec{o}^{\,t}
```

the superscript is moved a bit to the right. One might perhaps let TeX do some computations in order that the shift to the right of the superscript is automatic.

Answer (score 42):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv{o}^t \ \vv{o^t}$
$\vec{o}^{\,t}$
\end{document}
```

(I have included egreg's code to make the comparison easier.)

The first two are done using the `esvect` package, the third is egreg's code.
[image: The visual comparison.]

Answer (score 17):

How about something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vo}{\vec{o}\@ifnextchar{^}{\,}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\vec{o}^t o$ $\vo^t o$ 

$\vec{o} o$ $\vo o$

$\vec{o}^t_t o$ $\vo^t_t o$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks all right for `$\vo^t$`. (The `^` must be immediately after `\vo`.) I don't know how to make just the superscript shift in `$\vo^t_t$`.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar) is a discussion of how `\@ifnextchar` works.

Answer (score 4):

```
$\overrightarrow{A}$  this one for simple vector
$\overrightarrow{A}^{value}$  This one for superscript
$\overrightarrow{A}_{value}$  This one for subscript.
```

Hope this will help you. It's working in mine.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE, could you show it with a MWE? though it might work `\overrightarrow\neq\vec`, imo.

Comment: @Raaja what is MWE?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put y into the whole bracket like:

```
\vec{o^t}
```

This should give a result like:
[image: o^t]