# The sign of vector and degree are too close

Tags: symbols, vector, degrees

Why is the vector sign and "2" are too close? Never faced it before..... 
I wrote: `\vec{p}^2`
[image: The vec and degree]

Comment: You can separate it a bit with `$\vec{p}^{\,2}$`

Comment: @cmhughes Strangely, but in another tex file I don't have this problem. And your method doesn't work....

Comment: how about the answers here: [vector arrow with superscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16466)

Comment: @cmhughes I can't understand why I have the problem only at this document and don't have at any other document...

Comment: This is one place where `\vec{{}p}^{2}` looks definitely better.

Answer (score 2):

You won't have this problem with the `esvect` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}

\begin{document}

\[ {\vec p}^2\qquad \vv p^2 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]